# make web address in email newsletter appear as text not anchor link?

Tags: html, css, email, newsletter

This is the code I'm using.

```
<pre style="cursor: default !important; pointer-events: none !important; font:700 21px Arial; color:#fff!important; margin:12px; text-decoration: none !important;">
    info@royalsingapore.com | +65 6417 3059
</pre>
```

It is rendering as link when sent as an email newsletter from Madmimi.
I want it to be plain text. How to disable render as a link?

Comment: my trick is, to insert the link and style it like it's not a link.

Comment: Yes..I tried that just before I read your comment..It worked!

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, but i believe the fact that is it rendering as a link is up to the website that the email is being viewed on. I bet that the website has a function running on the body of the message that turns anything that looks like a link into an anchored link.

Answer (score 0):

Email systems such as google and specially apple on mobile recognize email addresses and phone numbers and make them clickable. you need to wrap it around in a anchor tag and give it a value of 000001 for example to make it black.